# Add rows to a csvfile without creating an intermediate copy

Tags: python

How can I add rows to a csvfile by editing in place? I want to avoid the pattern of writing to a temp file and then replacing the original, (pseudocode):

```
add_records_to_csv(newdata, infile, tmpfile)
delete(infile)
rename(tmpfile, infile)
```

Here's the actual function. The lines "# <--" are what I want to get rid of and/or condense into something more straightforward:

```
def add_records_to_csv(dic, csvfile):
    """ Append a dictionary to a CSV file.
        Adapted from http://pymotw.com/2/csv/
    """
    f_old = open(csvfile, 'rb')                         # <--
    csv_old = csv.DictReader(f_old)                     # <--

    fpath, fname = os.path.split(csvfile)               # <--
    csvfile_new = os.path.join(fpath, 'new_' + fname )  # <--
    print(csvfile_new)                                  # <--
    f = open(csvfile_new, 'wb')                         # <--

    try:
        fieldnames = sorted(set(dic.keys() + csv_old.fieldnames))
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        headers = dict( (n,n) for n in fieldnames )
        writer.writerow(headers)
        for row in csv_old:
            writer.writerow(row)
        writer.writerow(dic)
    finally:
        f_old.close()
        f.close()
    return csvfile_new
```

Comment: How big are the files (bytes)?  Can you post a few lines of the original and the expected result?

Comment: @wwii, [here](https://github.com/maphew/Speed-test/tree/master/stats/GEOMATT) are some of the csv's. Not a completely representative set, there are others which have different columns, which I now realize thanks to Dan will have to be handled separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your new row has the same structure as the existing records the following will work:

```
import csv

def append_record_to_csv(dic, csvfile):
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
        # discover order of field names in header row
        fieldnames = next(csv.reader(f))   
    with open(csvfile, 'ab') as f:
        # assumes that dic contains only fieldnames in csv file
        dwriter = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=fieldnames) 
        dwriter.writerow(dic)
```

On the other hand, if your new row as a different structure than the existing rows a csv file is probably the wrong file format.  In order to add a new column to a csv file every row needs to be edited.  The performance of this approach is very bad and will be quite noticeable with a large csv file.

Comment: It's a good straightforward approach. The problem is that @mattwilkie's code says he will sometimes want to add new fields when adding new rows: `fieldnames = sorted(set(dic.keys() + csv_old.fieldnames))`

Comment: @DanLenski:  Fair enough.  I've added a comment to the code documenting that it assumes the fieldnames are identical.  I think this assumption is justified because the OP's current approach would error out rewriting the old rows to the new csv file if new headings were introduced.

Comment: I believe the [default behavior of `DictWriter` is to replace fields missing from the dictionary with blanks](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter); the OP may be relying on this behavior without realizing it. On the other hand, if there are *extra* fields in the dictionary it raises an exception. Kind of a confusing combination.

Comment: @DanLenski.  You are correct.  `dw = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['a','b']);dw.writerow({'a':'2'})` runs without exception on my computer.

Comment: Good point about CSV being a bad format for adding records whose fields may change. JSON might be reasonable in some cases, though a key-value store or RDBMS is probably the right solution for longer-term use.

Comment: Thanks for a solution to the question asked. Unfortunately as @DanLenski points out I have different columns incoming, so my goal has just expanded to _"append to final.csv in place, from input.csv which probably has some new columns"_. An expansion in scope that probably demands a new question(?)

Answer (score 3):

This is not going to be possible in general. Here is the reason, from *your* code:

```
fieldnames = sorted(set(dic.keys() + csv_old.fieldnames))
```

To me, this says that **at least in some cases** your new row contains columns that were not in the previous rows. When you add a row like this, you will have to update the header of the file (the first line), in addition to appending new rows at the end. If you need to have the column names in alphabetized order, then you may have to rearrange the fields in all the other rows in order to retain the ordering of the columns.

Because you may need to edit the first line of the file, in addition to appending new lines at the end and possibly editing all the lines in-between, there isn't a reasonable way to make this work in-place.

My suggestion is to try and figure out, ahead of time, all the fields/columns that you may need to include so that you guarantee your program will never have to edit the header and can simply add new rows.

Comment: ahhh, right. I'll have to group my input files into sets with identical columns and/or figure out how to read each csvfile and output into single harmonized file. This just got bigger than I realized!

Comment: It sounds like you're at risk of inventing your own relational database system :-). If you really need to store an unpredictable bunch of "random combinations of keys and values", then a document database like MongoDB or a real RDBMS with [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) support like PostgreSQL is a good solution. It all depends on what you're trying to *do* with this data and how much of it there is/will be.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to merge some 85 separate csv files with nearly but not quite identical columns (they have common set) into a single table that I can then analyse with Excel. Here's a sample: https://github.com/maphew/Speed-test/tree/master/stats/GEOMATT

Comment: @mattwilkie, I've had to do something similar before with CSV files that were almost-but-not-quite identical in format. If it's feasible to harmonize the file formats before combining them, I think you'll save yourself a lot of pain.

Comment: it turns out there are only 4 distinct sets of columns, so it will be feasible to group them and do away with the code that merges and re-orders headers. Thank you for pointing my attention in a more profitable direction.